# How to do passive:false event listeners in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to do `event.preventDefault()` in an `onWheel` handler, because of a niche UI requirement where mousewheel will control a 'zoom' effect in a certain element.

But React sets `passive: true` on wheel events, so `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work.

Is there some escape hatch that lets you attach events manually in a safe way?

The only way I know is to use a ref and call `ref.current.addEventListener` within a `useEffect`. And I've tried that and it *seems* to work, but I think it goes against official advice, because (if I understand correctly) React won't know to re-run the effect if `ref.current` changes. And that would be a serious bug if it happens in the wild. Is there a safer way to do it?

Comment: You can actually use ref, you just need to not forget to clean up your useEffect with a `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. If React does not provide a way for you to do it, then use the "escape hatch" they provide to get around that. Infact, scrolling is listed as one of the valid use cases for refs here https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs

The ref element should not change as it is being managed by React. And if it does, it will trigger a re-render where you can catch any changes.